# GLUT library problems while compiling OpenGL

Tags: c, windows, opengl, makefile

I'm trying to compile a sample from a project, the following code is the makefile:

```
CC = gcc 
MACHINE= $(shell uname -s)
#declaration des options du compilateur
#PG_FLAGS = -DOPENGL_1_5

ifeq ($(MACHINE), Darwin)
GL_LDFLAGS = -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -framework Cocoa -framework 
Carbon
else
GL_LDFLAGS = -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglut
endif

CFLAGS = -Wall 
LDFLAGS = -lm $(GL_LDFLAGS)
PROGNAME = palette
HEADERS = image.h

SOURCES = Main.c ppm.c fonctions.c
```

I tried: "mingw32-make" and i got:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
 gcc  Main.o ppm.o fonctions.o -lm -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglut -o  palette
 C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64- 
 w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Makefile:25: recipe for target 'palette' failed
 mingw32-make: *** [palette] Error
```

but i have the glut library installed
and i am using windows 10

Comment: How did you install glut library? Is it placed in your project?

Comment: no i have placed it in C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib

Comment: this path commonly used for static libraries. you need to add this path to your `PATH` environment variable or replace it somewhere else. also you can add additional `-L` flag to you linking stage to help your linker find this lib.

Comment: i have added the link C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib to the path and nothing happend :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for this problem

GLUT library have been abandoned with the most recent version 3.7. Also, GLUT's license is incompatible with some software distributions .... so i used freeGLUT  insted of it and it works

and there is the link to download it :

https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/

goodluck evryone :)